# Apply a function to each element of an array in Python

Tags: python, poisson

I am trying to do two things in Python:

1. Simulate 100 random draws from a Poisson distribution. I have done this by:

```
sample100 = poisson.rvs(mu=5,size=100)
```

2. Take the above sample, and apply an UMP test I've generated to each individual observation (e.g., test the hypothesis against each individual observation). The test should accept the null hypothesis if the observation has a value < 8; reject with probability ~50% if observation has value = 8; reject if observation has value > 8

I cannot figure out how to do the second part of this. The function code I've made is:

```
    def optionaltest(y,k,g):
    
        if (y > k):
            return 1
        if (y == k):
            if rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885: return 1
            else: return 0
        if (y < k):
            return 0
```

But there are two issues - apparently if (y==k) is invalid syntax. Second, even if I remove that part, I can't actually apply the function to sample100 since it is an array.

How can I modify this to make it work? Clearly, I'm very new to Python but I have been scouring the internet for hours. Perhaps I should change how I'm generating my sample data so I can apply a function to it? Maybe there's a way to apply a function to each element of an array? How do I make the test logic work when the output = k (which I will set to 8 in this case)?

EDIT/UPDATE:
Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
    def optionaltest(y):
    
        if (y > 8):
            return 1
        if (y == 8):
            if np.random.uniform(0,1) >= 0.4885: return 1
            else: return 0
        if (y < 8):
            return 0
```

I was able to apply that test to my array data via:

```
results_sample100 = list(map(optimaltest, sample100))
cl.Counter(results_sample100)
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the "invalid syntax" error or stack trace? As for the second part what do you need to *do* with these results? Can you just create an empty `results = []` list and loop through your data to apply the function to each item and append its return value to your `results` list? You can use a `for` loop, the `map` function, or a list comprehension. I'd prefer the last one as it's a lot clearer than `map`

Comment: You can convert the array to a list and use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid python syntax

```
if rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885 then 1
    else 0
```

Instead, you could do this:

```
return 1 if rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885 else 0
```

You could also do something more verbose but potentially more straightforward (this is often a matter of taste), like this:

```
def optionaltest(y,k,g):

    if (y > k):
        return 1
    if (y == k):
        if rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if (y < k):
        return 0
```

Or even like this:

```
def optionaltest(y,k,g):

    if (y > k):
        return 1
    if (y == k) and rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

For this question:

> Maybe there's a way to apply a function to each element of an array?

You can use a for-loop or `map` a function over a list:

```
results = []
for elem in somelist:
     results.append(my_function(elem))
```

Alternately:

```
results = list(map(my_function, somelist))
```

Your function takes three arguments, though, and it's not clear to me where those are coming from. Is your list a list of tuples?

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really helpful. I've changed my function to:
`def optionaltest(y):
    if (y > 8):
        return 1
    if (y == k):
        if rand(uniform(0,1)) >= 0.4885:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if (y < 8):
        return 0`

I'm hoping I can test each element in the array against that if logic - so in this case, y would be an elemeny in the array

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can use the `map` method easily.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out based on your feedback - thanks so much!

Comment: Sure. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

syntax error is

in Python if condition then..else becomes

```
if condition:
       pass
else:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

For applying function on your list's elements you can convert your list to a pandas dataframe. Then use apply function. For example if your list name is " data " and your function is "func" do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3']
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['column_name'])

result = df.apply(func)
```